# Why it's taking only first element in the array?

Tags: java

```
for (int i=0;i<max.length;i++){
    System.out.print(max[i]);
    if(max[i]>low ){
        low = max[i];
        if(low<=b){
            soln=low;
        }
    }   
}
System.out.println();

if(soln==0){
    System.out.println(neg);
} else {
    System.out.println(soln);
}
```

output 8

Well, I have given value of neg=-1,low=0, b=10, keyboards=2, drive=3
and my array is

[3 1]

[5 2 8]

I have added the keyboard and drive value stored it in max array. When I compare those max array values with b if(max[i]>low), it should return 9 after the completion of loop. But it is taking only first element in the max array. I don't know why? Please help me.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `if(max[i]<low)` , not `if(max[i]>low)`.

Comment: I hope, it will never enter into the if loop, If(max[I]<low) because low=0 and max array elements are greater then 0. The if condition will never execute until there is a negative value in the max array values.

Comment: I have taken soln=0 to store the result when compared. And neg=-1, in case the condition never executes and soln will be 0. and -1 will be returned as output. ex if b=10 and arry is[9][9] and that addition of both array value will be stored in max and output would be -1(since 18>b). Another ex [3,1 ] [5,2,8] and it should return 9(8+1=9 which is<b) and it is returning 8(3+5=8). Taking only first element from max array, loop is not continuing or don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

where you wrote this:
`(max[i]>low)`

it should be this: 
`(max[i]<low)`

Comment: Oh, my bad! I was supposed to use high instead of low. I just took wrong name for variable. I am beginner here, I couldn't post my code properly. Anyway thanks, I solved it.